# How to reference derived types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Having object A:

```
interface A {
   boolProp: boolean,
   stringProp: string,
   numberProp: number,
   ...other props/methods...
}
```

Then I want to have objects, which holds one of the A properties and defines default value for it, other properties are irrelevant to this issue.

```
interface B {
    prop: keyof A,
    default: typeof keyof A,
   ...other props/methods...
}
```

I want to get TS error when I try to set default value of different type

```
const b: B = {
  prop: 'stringProp',
  default: true, // expecting to get TS error as true cannot be assigned to string
};
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want a union type which holds all valid `prop`/`default` combinations. This can be programmatically generated with a mapped type which maps over the keys of `A` and is indexed with `keyof A`.

```
type B = {
    [K in keyof A]: {
        prop: K
        default: A[K]
    }
}[keyof A] & {
    /* ... put all the other props of B here */ 
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm4EYD2BANgApQEAOAXMoSRHCADQ64DOYUoA5uVbU7cQPVrmQgArgFs80fjQky5ULAF8sWMAE9KKAELIAvJja4A2gGlkoZAGsI2gjDQBdWtnFfklCostm3gAmEPCSxGC0qFaugRpq5g5OLqiuyABkpl4EYAAW8n7sgly8gQD0AFTIAHS1PpJgyHDExMh5KDn5UD6FyM7Ihl0oFWXI6kA)

Comment: awesome, works pretty well, can you please explain or provide link to ts docs what feature is following reference `}[keyof A]`? Thank you 

Comment: Its [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). The docs only show access singular properties like `"age"`, but you can also supply a union like `keyof A` to get a union of the results.

Comment: Note that you should probably write `const b = {...} satisfies B` (TS 4.9) when using this approach, as annotating `b` with `B` will widen your type and be less useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a generic. It won't create a union type:

```js
interface B<T extends keyof A> {
    prop: T,
    default: A[T]
//    ...other props/methods...
}

const b: B<'stringProp'> = {
  prop: 'stringProp',
  default: true, // error
};
```

Of course the repetition of 'stringProp' is annoying. You may use a function or a class constructor instead and check the arguments passed to it, for example:

```js
const createB = <T extends keyof A>(prop: T, defaultVal: A[T]) => ({ prop, default: defaultVal });

const b = createB('stringProp', true);
// error                        ----
```